# Javascript => Match array elements to each other by date

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, dictionary, typescript

I have one array with over 50 object. This array is a result of concat(ing) two arrays. Elements in this array are Objects and each object has key 'date' with the date string in format:

```
`"2017-03-31T11:30:00.000Z"`
```

And key 'caption' with text. So I have elements like:

```
[
    {date: "2017-03-31T11:30:00.000Z", caption: "text_1"},
    {date: "2016-03-31T11:30:00.000Z", caption: "text_2"},
    {date: "2016-03-31T11:30:00.000Z", caption: "text_3"},
    {date: "2017-03-31T11:30:00.000Z", caption: "text_4"}
]
```

In Ruby, which I know much better and deeper, you can map elements in array and return new one and condition return by if statement. I was wondering if there is something like that in JS, I am currently looping through array and matching each element to others but it isn't the most performant way. I would like to do something like:

`let newArray = myArray.map( (a,b) => { if (a.date === b.date) { return {text1: a.caption, text2: b.caption}}});`

So result would be:

```
[
  {text1: "text_1", text2: "text_4"},
  {text1: "text_2", text2: "text_3"}
]
```

Does something like this, something elegant as well as performant exists?

Thanks...

Comment: So click the `<>` snippet editor and create a [mcve] then we can better help

Comment: var result = array.filter(i=> i.date == date);

Comment: Not really for `map()` since you only return conditionally. Resultant array will still have same length as original but be full of holes

Comment: Your question is unclear. There are different methods in JS that suit different use-case. But remember, when you say *most performant*, there is no function associated with array that can beat `for`. So I'd suggest you to write it using `for` first. Also your code will not work as `.map` signature is `(item, index, array)`

Comment: `Array#reduce()` would be more appropriate since you are reducing. Or any loop and conditionally push into a previously declared empty array

Comment: @NairAthul OP is not filtering...they are returning different data than original array elements conditionally

Comment: Would you like it on the concatenated array or on the original arrays?

Comment: Are there always pairs and no orphans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is:
No, there's no functionality in Javascript that accomplishes what you want as elegantly as you wish (not sure about performant).

For your particular use case, I would simply create a new object that uses the date as key and collects the different captions, then convert that object to an array:

```
const collected = {};

myArray.forEach((entry) => {
    if (entry.date in collected) {
        collected[entry.date].text2 = entry.caption;
    } else {
        collected[entry.date] = { text1: entry.caption };
    }
});

const newArray = Object.keys(collected).map(key => collected[key]);
```

Comment: At the end I changed my approach and didn't concat the arrays. I followed your approach and adjusted it a bit to my use and it resolved in much faster data formation. Thanks for great suggestion.